# Plugin architecture with multple plugin types (XNA)

Tags: c#, architecture, plugins, xna

I'm looking to design a multi purpose RPG engine for myself in XNA, and would like to make it reliant on plugins. For the most part, I understand the whole general concept... and I have a basic IPlugin interface.

However, the problem arises when you realize you need several types of plugins for different systems, and a way to accommodate it all. In fact, you could say I'm trying to make everything modulated. Should I use multiple interfaces, that implement different things? Different host interfaces? Any tips are appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you give an example of a problem you face ?

Comment: More or less the design. The services a battle system plugin will need will differ from a menu system, but then again there are multiple types of menus. And a battle system might need to hook into something to create windows. Would I be better off with some kind of scripting system? Do I need multiple plugin interfaces and hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends how you gonna manage and also look from performance perspective on this. BUt yu can do something like this. *Pseudocode*:

```
public class Host {

   HostEventDispatcher dispatcher = new HostEventDispatcher ();
   MenuTypes {File, Tools, Options, Help}
   ToolBarTypes {MainBar}

   AddSubMenuToMainMenu(IMenu menu, MenuTypes hostMenu);
   AddSubMenuToMainMenu(IToolbar toolbar, ToolBarTypes hostToolbar);   

   public void LoadPlugin(IPlugin plugin) 
   {
       plugin.Dispatcher = dispatcher;
   }
}

interface IMenu {/* control warpper implementation */} 

interface IToolBar {/* control wrapper implementation */}

public HostEventDispatcher {
   //raises events to subscribers (Host, plugins)

   /***** event list ***/
}

public interface IPlugin 
{
    Dispatcher {get;set} //using this plugin can raise/recieve evets to/from Host.
}
```

Very basic idea. But it for sure will become more complicated in *real* implementation, and can easily become much more complicated after. Keep attention on complexity as it affects performance cause it's something that easily can be missed following "maximum flexibility" pattern.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `IPlugin` interface. You have an `IEnemy` interface and an `IWeapon` interface etc.

Comment: How does help with plugins? I want to be able to say - swap out a battle system keeping the core components that any given said system would need access to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use components, either your own or gameComponents, that are by default inactive.
Then you can yourself choose which ones to activate with for example a xml doc.

```
<Plugins>
  <Plugin name="MyNamespace.CombatManager"/>
  <Plugin name="MyNamespace.GuiManager"/>
</Plugins>
```

And then you can activate the selected plugins:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
public void ActivatePlugins(string filePath)
{
    XElement plugins = XElement.Load(filePath);
    foreach(var plugin in plugins.Elements("Plugin"))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Components.Count; i++)
        {
            if(Type.GetType(plugin.Value) == Components[i].GetType()) 
            { ((GameCompoent)Components[i]).Enabled = true; }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```